# Excel formula for return a "value" if a condition's meet and then the sum of a "value" should meet another condition

Tags: excel-formula

[image: Picture]

I'm trying to code this formula to solves some conditions :
For cell P29 and so on, if cell P27 is " " return " ", if sum of cell P27 and so on is 90% of C27 value return C29/5, and the total value of sum P29 and so on should be C29, if the total value of sum P29 and so on is C29, the next cell should " "

Help u guys understand my question, thank uu !!

i've tried this formula `=IF(P27="";"";IF(SUM($F$27:P$27)<($C$27)*90%;"";$C$29/$D$29))`, the sum of P29 and so on cannot meet C29, because the next cell give " " value

Comment: Welcome to SO. If you provide some sample data (best by using [Markdown Table Generator](https://www.tablesgenerator.com/markdown_tables) (read [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/16578424) for an explanation)) and your expected output it would be much easier to help you!. Reading [ask] and [repro] will help you to improve your question. Maybe this link will help you too: [Stack Overflow question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/).

Comment: So if you move the bracket from `($C$27)*90%` to `($C$27*90%)`, does that work better?

Comment: it doesnt work, i think the problem is the second if condition, that state if true give " " answer